# Redis how to persist multiple keys at once

Tags: redis

In Redis, is it possible to call PERSIST on multiple keys at once? For example, say I have the following commands:

```
MULTI
SETEX mykey 10 "foo"
SETEX myotherkey 10 "bar"
EXEC

// wait x number of seconds

PERSIST mykey
PERSIST myotherkey
```

I want to guarantee that either `mykey` and `myotherkey` are both persisted, or are both expired.

In theory at least, in the example above if the two `PERSIST` commands were run after waiting almost exactly 10 seconds, then it's possible that only one of them succeed in persisting the key, right? And I doubt that wrapping the two `PERSIST` commands in `MULTI`/`EXEC` helps since the commands themselves will still succeed even if only one of the keys is actually persisted.

Answer (score 0):

`persist` returns

- `1`: if the timeout is removed
- `0`: if the key doesn't exists or doesn't have a `TTL`.

In the transaction even one of the key doesn't have an expire time, the other key will be persisted.

I set `firstkey` with the TTL of 300 seconds, `secondkey` without the TTL.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> setex firstkey 300 val
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set secondkey val
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> multi
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> persist firstkey
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> persist secondkey
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> exec
1) (integer) 1
2) (integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl firstkey
(integer) -1
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl secondkey
(integer) -1
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

When `exec` is issued, the order of responses are the same as the commands issued. `firstkey` is persisted(`1`) and `secondkey` already persisted(`0`) since it didn't have a timeout. Both doesn't have any timeout since the `TTL` returns `-1`.

Comment: But in my example both keys have timeout... So I'm saying that one of them might actually expire (and be deleted) while the other one might be persisted.

Comment: @shmth i understand what do you mean. What i don't get is that if `wait x number of seconds` > 10 then you will loose both keys. Why are you setting a TTL if you are going to persist them ? It would be clear if you explain your scenario.

Comment: @shmth what about using `hash` type for your case - you set fields as your key name - values as hash values. you expire/persist the single hash. since the hash has both of your keys, it will live all or die all.